# Pandas dataframe not exporting all rows to csv (but all are displayed in terminal)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've started playing with pandas and web scraping, the code seems to work and all result rows are displayed in the terminal when I run the code, however when I  export it to csv it only displays half of the result rows. It might have something to do that I'm iterating through urls however then I'm not sure why the results are still displayed correctly in the terminal.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=Scrum+master&l=London', 'https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q=Scrum+master&l=London&start=10']

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    job_results = soup.find(id='resultsCol')
    jobs = job_results.find_all(class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard')

    titles = [job.find(class_='jobtitle').get_text() for job in jobs]
    descriptions = [job.find('div', attrs={'class': 'summary'}).get_text() for job in jobs]

  jobs_filtered = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'title' : titles,
            'description' : descriptions,
        })

    print(jobs_filtered)
    jobs_filtered.to_csv('jobs_filtered11.csv')
```

Comment: When you say that only half the data is in the `.csv` do you mean only data from one site? I ask because you are saving the results for all iterations to the same filename meaning that you are overwriting data.

Comment: Yes, data from one url, probably this is the issue, how could I fix that so that everything is added to the same file?  What really threw me off is that all results appeared in terminal.

Comment: Yeah it is being printed each time but because you are writing over the file you're only getting data from the last iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use append mode to get the required output.

```
jobs_filtered.to_csv('jobs_filtered11.csv', mode='a', header=False) # True for the first time if necessary
```